# Kepler 2.3 installation giving error

Tags: java, linux

we are trying to install Kepler 2.3 workflow on a Red Hat machine (its a virtual machine) having Java 1.6 (64 bit). But we are getting following error

*[null] Error occurred during initialization of VM
*[null] Too small initial heap for new size specified

Any idea what is wrong? If it helps, I have installed it on my local machine and it is working fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying a larger heap size as a JVM arguement:

`java -Xms512m -Xmx512m YourApp`

Answer (score 0):

kepler 2.3 starts with an initial heap of 5MB which is to small on some 64 bit systems.
To change it modify $HOME/KeplerData/kepler.modules/build-area/settings/memory.xml

change the "min" key to something larger, 10m should already be sufficient.